# Php Mysql Daily Results in loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

```
<?php
    $query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, bill.amount, bill.cheque, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
     "FROM bill, bill_agents ".
     "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ".  
     "ORDER BY bill.date ASC";

    $result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die('Error, query failed1'); 
    if ( mysql_num_rows( $result4 ) > 0 ) {
        mysql_data_seek(  $result4, 0 );
?>

<?php while( $row4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result4, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) { ?> 

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row4['name']; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <?php } } ?>
</table>
```

Till here this code is working fine for me

billTable Structure

[image]

bill_agents Table Structure

[image]

Current result display
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMH3P.jpg

**What I am trying to display is in result I want daily collection report day day 1 to day 31 (and also it should by sum of amount and cheque) how is it possble**

Result should be like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S08or.jpg

Also I am getting error While Using `"GROUP BY bill.agent_id".`  in the same SQL that used above and its pasted below.

```
$query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, bill.amount, bill.cheque, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
    "FROM bill, bill_agents ".
    "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ".   
    "GROUP BY bill.agent_id".
    "ORDER BY bill.date ASC";
```

Comment: Current Result Display http://i.stack.imgur.com/tMH3P.jpg result should be like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/S08or.jpg

Comment: You need a space after `"GROUP BY bill.agent_id"`.

Comment: @Teodor Blazhev you are right and how it is possible to diply daily reulst

Comment: You should use [SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/group-by-modifiers.html) in your SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query. `GROUP_CONCAT` will give you the list of check numbers and `sum of all the check amount that belongs to one agent`.

```
SELECT 
        bill.agent_id,
        bill.date,
        SUM(bill.amount),
        GROUP_CONCAT(bill.cheque),
        bill_agents.id,
        bill_agents.name
    FROM
        bill,
        bill_agents
    WHERE
        bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY bill.agent_id
    ORDER BY bill.date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic answer would be something like:-

SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, bill.amount, bill.cheque, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name , SUM(bill.amount)".
    "FROM bill_agents LEFT OUTER JOIN bill ON bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id  ".
    "WHERE  YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ".
    "GROUP BY bill.agent_id".
    "ORDER BY bill.date ASC

However the big problem is that there are plenty of days where an agent has no activity. When you need is a table to generate the days of the month (which could just be a select of a range of numbers added to the first day of the month), which you cross join against the agents to get every possibly combination of agent and day of the month. The you left join that against the bill table.

Bit more of a play. Not tested so probably some typos and not quite sure which figures you want summed up, but hopefully will give you the idea.

```
SELECT bill.agent_id, MonthDays.DayOfMonth, bill.date, bill.amount, bill.cheque, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name , SUM(bill.amount)
FROM bill_agents
CROSS JOIN (SELECT a.i+b.i*10 AS DaysToAdd, LAST_DAY(NOW()) - (a.i+b.i*10) AS DayOfMonth
FROM integers a, integers b
HAVING DaysToAdd < DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))) MonthDays
LEFT OUTER JOIN bill ON bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND bill.date = MonthDays.DayOfMonth
GROUP BY bill.agent_id
ORDER BY bill.date ASC, MonthDays.DayOfMonth
```